# Drupal 6 incorrect mail messages when using mimemail

Tags: email, drupal, smtp

I have a problem with the mimemail module on drupal 6.
I'm developing a site on a virtual Unix server and the SMTP server is Micorsoft Exchange (on another server of course) and I'm using mimemail and SMTP modules to send emails.

When I configure the SMTP module by itself, everything is correct and I receive the test message in the correct format.

If I enable mimemail, set the "Use mime mail for all messages" and then I configure the SMTP, the message arrives but it is not correctly encoded.

I hope that someone can give me an help.
I spent a lot of time searching the web for a solution but I was not able to find an answer.

Here is the test message I receive:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--ca2a0ce37a649a90e1efc6d650f2387c
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="44b02f56426ca5bf19322ab80ca53d99"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


--44b02f56426ca5bf19322ab80ca53d99
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

If you receive this message it means your site is capable of sending e-mail.


--44b02f56426ca5bf19322ab80ca53d99
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <style type="text/css">
     <!--
     @charset "UTF-8";

body{background:#FFF;}
*{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#006;}

     -->
   </style>
     </head>
 <body id="mimemail-body" class="mail-smtp-smtp-test">
   <div id="center">
     <div id="main">
       <p>If you receive this message it means your site is capable of sending e-mail.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>

--44b02f56426ca5bf19322ab80ca53d99--

--ca2a0ce37a649a90e1efc6d650f2387c--
```